# Can I safely delete the .cpanm/work directory?

Tags: perl, cpan

I've used cpanm to install cpan perl modules on my system, however the .cpanm/work directory is 100's of megs and I'd like to delete it.

Can I delete this directory without adversely affecting my cpanm installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can.

But, from the cpanm 1.1.2, it automatically cleans up the work directories older than 7 days. You can change this number by using `--auto-cleanup` option:

```
--auto-cleanup
  Specifies the number of days in which cpanm's work directories expire. 
  Defaults to 7, which means old work directories will be cleaned up in one week.

  You can set the value to 0 to make cpan never cleanup those directories.
```